# Lost my answer on deleted question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Note; I have read [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) but I didn't see an answer to my question.

A couple of days ago, I answered a question for a new user, and I worked on my answer for about 40 minutes. The question didn't receive any downvotes, and wasn't marked as a duplicate or anything, but the next day the question was deleted *[by the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444333/screen-managment-xna-c-sharp/)*.

All I can figure is I answered the user's question, or he solved it himself, and he deleted the question, either because he thought he was supposed to or didn't want to mark my answer as so for some reason. The question he asked is asked fairly often in the XNA tag, and so I was surprised it wasn't marked as a duplicate (I guess this is because no one really provided a complete answer to any of the other questions...).

So this is really bothering me: *There's no way for me to get my answer back*?

If someone asks the question again, I would like to just be able to repost what I had before (since it doesn't exist anymore). Or even because this question is asked fairly often (I did google searches for it a couple years ago and could only find a Microsoft example that doesn't exist now), I would like to ask and answer my own question, but I don't really want to type out the whole answer again. So I guess these are my two questions:

1. *There's no way for me to see my **own** answer?*
2. When something like this happens, is it okay to post and answer my own question about it?

Comment: visit your profile. Click answers. At the bottom is a *deleted recent answers* link

Comment: @juergend Which doesn't help him if the question is deleted; he doesn't have permission to view deleted questions that are not his own.  That would only help him if he deleted the answer himself, if a mod deleted it, or if enough regular users voted/flagged for deletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There's no way for me to see my own answer?

You can ask here and a 10k user can look at it and recover the full post for you; I quoted the full answer below.

You can certainly repost the question (but do attribute it to the original asker), but I've flagged the post for moderator attention instead. I see no reason for that question to be deleted, that post should just be un-deleted, and voted to undelete myself. If a moderator or enough 10k+ users agree, it'll be moved back to being visible.

> If I were you, I would create a `ScreenManager` class. You could start
>   with something like this:
>
> ```
> public class ScreenManager
> {
>     List<GameScreen> screens;
>     bool isinitialized = false;
>
>     public override void Initialize()
>     {
>         base.Initialize();
>         isinitialized = true;
>     }
>
>     protected override void LoadContent()
>     {
>          foreach (GameScreen screen in screens)
>              screen.LoadContent();
>     }
>
>     public void AddScreen(GameScreen screen)
>     {
>         screens.Add(screen);
>         if (isinitialized) screen.LoadContent();
>     }
>
>     // also create a removescreen
>
>     public void Draw(Gametime gametime)
>     {
>         foreach (GameScreen screen in screens)
>         {
>             screen.Draw(gametime);
>         }
>     }
>     // also create a similar method for Updating
> }
> ```
>
> You could make ScreenManager a `DrawableGameComponent` (recommended),
>   or you could have the maingame call `ScreenManager.Update()` and
>   `ScreenManager.Draw()` in it's respective methods. Finally, you'd have
>   to create an abstract `GameScreen` class that has update and draw
>   methods, and then have all your other Game Screens inherit from the
>   `GameScreen` class. hopefully this will give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks Martijn Pieters. I thought about asking someone to recover it, but I decided I probably shouldn't ask 10K users to retrieve something like that.

Comment: It's still your work; you wrote it and licensed it under the CC wiki license when you posted it on Stack Overflow. You of all people have the right to request it to be recovered.

Comment: So in the future, if something like this happens, could I ask a moderator (or maybe someone else with 10k rep) to recover it?

Comment: Yes, just post a question here on Meta.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It seems excessive to be posting on meta for something like this, especially as a first solution to a problem.

Comment: @Servy: I have no problem with it; I've seen questions like these only once every few months. It's not as if we are advertising it somewhere.

Comment: @MartijnPieters When you start answering questions telling people to post such questions yes, you're advertising it.  I'm not saying that's never appropriate, but it shouldn't be the first solution people turn to every single time any question is ever deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, the question was undeleted. Thanks for flagging and voting to undelete it.

Comment: @davidsbro: Indeed, a moderator responded to my flag and undeleted the post. Do note, if this is a question often asked, perhaps you should flag posts as duplicates instead in the future.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Thanks. btw I would've flagged it, but I had never seen anyone give a thorough answer, so that's why I answered it.

Answer (score 3):

If you've provided a good answer to a question that was deleted by the user, and you don't believe it should have been, you can always flag the question (or one of your own posts, if you can't see the question) and let us know about it. We can see the history of deleted posts on your account, and can undelete the appropriate question if we think it should be restored. I might not overrule the community if they were the ones who voted to delete it, but I usually restore questions that the asker removed in this fashion (I don't like it when people decide to take their ball and go home).

Someone flagged this question, so I saw it and was able to undelete the question. Your answer now has an upvote on it, which will prevent the user from deleting this same question by themselves again.

Answer (score 2):

> There's no way for me to see my own answer?

[Google Cache FTW](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:nBmzsumfigQJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/21444333/screen-managment-xna-c-sharp+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)

You could also earn 10k reputation on the site ;)

If the Google cache doesn't have it, doesn't have a sufficiently recent version, or you can't find it there, then the next place to go would be to use the "contact us" option on the site footer to contact someone on the site who will be able to provide you with your content.

> When something like this happens, is it okay to post and answer my own question about it?

Yes, it most certainly is.  That said, you should properly attribute any content that is not your own.

And of course, if you're going to post the question yourself then you're saying that you feel it is a quality question, and are willing to accept responsibility for that.  If it's not a quality question you either shouldn't post it, or fix it up into a quality question first.  Posting a bad question just as a placeholder for an answer (even a very good answer) is not appropriate.  The question and answer will each be judged independently, even when self-answering, and both should be of high quality.

Comment: Ok, wow, thank you Servy. I didn't know about the Google Cache. That's really helpful

Comment: The Google cache only lasts for so long however; at some point in the near future Google will purge it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That shouldn't be an issue with respect to this particular problem.  Generally if the answer is that valuable it'll get upvotes if not deleted quickly, thus preventing deletion.  It'd cover the majority of cases, if not every single one.  For those remaining exceptional cases using the "contact us" to request the data, for example, would be fine.

Comment: I'm trying to get that 10k rep...but it's not that easy. ;) Just trying for 1k right now.

Comment: @Servy: It happens from time to time, that an OP speed-deletes after receiving an answer before anyone can vote. Happened two or three times to me too.

Comment: @Servy: and the Google cache doesn't include the full markdown cache; a 10k user can retrieve that no problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, an answer can be deleted right away before there can be any votes.  *That was my point*.  If this happens, it means the answer was deleted *right away*, so the issue is recent, and the content is still in the cache.

Comment: @Servy: Not always; sometimes someone may find out too late that their post was nuked. All they have is a link in their history or something.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't say *always*, I'm saying *usually*.  It's going to be a highly effective solution in the vast majority of cases.  Rejecting a solution out of hand because there are some situations in which it won't work makes no sense.  If you are in one of those situations where you can't use the cached version, then you obviously need to do something else, but for those that can, they should.

Comment: @Servy: I never rejected your solution! I merely pointed out that the Google Cache is transitory.